# Laravel, Mailgun 'Class GuzzleHttp\Client name not found'

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, mailgun

I am receiving the following error shown below when attempting to use Mailgun to send a confirmation email from my Laravel project.

Here is my .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandbox......mailgun.org
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@sandbox......mailgun.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-....
MAIL_FROM=cloud@sandbox.....mailgun.org
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Here is my mail.php file:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
```

And this is in my composer.json:

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2"
```

Any help of any kind at all would be so greatly appreciated. I simply don't understand the issue.

Comment: have you run `composer install` ?

Comment: @davidzucco Check by doing a `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload` once

Comment: @davidzucco also try installing the package like this in your composer.json `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0"`

Comment: @davidzucco Most important do a `php artisan config:clear` as well

Answer (score 1):

These are the possible quick fixes have a try in the order I explained,

1) do a `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload` once

2) clear the config cache by running `php artisan config:clear`

If nothing works try changing the package to `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0"` and run the above commands to install the package and clear the config cache.

It should work when you run the second step.